# Entity Framework POCO - Modelling a 0:1 or 1:1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework

Can someone confirm that I have coded the correct relationship between 2 POCO classes so that I have an Order object that can have 0 or 1 CreditCard objects and a CreditCard object that must belong to an Order (some class properties removed for brevity).

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCard
{
    public int CreditCardId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public CardType Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

In my OnModelCreating method I have the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(or => or.CreditCard).WithRequired(lu => lu.Order);
}
```

Hopefully the above code is specifying that an Order has an optional CreditCard but the Credit Card requires an Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF, 1:1 and 1:0..1 (and even 0..1:0..1) relationships [require that the primary key is shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16081139/439024) between all related entities.  Your `CreditCardId` and `OrderId` values must be the same.

Your configuration seend to specify the relationship correctly, but the `OrderId` property in `CreditCart` is redundant and may cause problems.  In `CreditCard` you may need to mark `CreditCardId` as not being server-generated too.

Comment: Hi Olly, how do you mark a key as not being server generated?

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>().Property(t => t.MyProperty)
              .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`

Comment: thanks Olly, your suggestion seems to work well so will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an o/r mapper such as Entity Framework or NHibernate, I would model this as one-to-many and use the public property to limit the collection to one item (actually I don't know if that is possible in EF). Basically, I treat this as a 1:n where n is set by a business rule. I don't love this solution but in my experience that's the best way to model it and [I haven't found a better solution in the last almost four years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208796/modeling-one-to-zero-or-one-relationships-z-cardinality).